# R: calculating mean of positive values in every column of a data frame

Tags: r

I want to calculate the mean of every column of a date frame. But only the positive values should be considered. The positive mean-values of every column are summarised in one vector.

My code:

```
x <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample(-5000:7000, 1000, rep = TRUE)))

meanxpositive <- c(NA)

for (n_col in 1:3) {     
    z <- mean(x[which(x[, ncol] > 0)])
    meanxpositive[n_col] <- z
}
```

This code don't work. Maybe someone have a better idea.

Comment: `sapply(x, function(a) mean(a[a>0]))`

Comment: Jesus, that was fast. But is it possible to do it inside a loop,too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sapply(x, function (y) mean(y[y > 0]))

colMeans(as.matrix(x) * (x > 0))
```

Comment: `colMeans(as.matrix(x) * (x > 0))` divides by the total number of rows.

Comment: Yes, too quick I was

Answer (score 2):

A `colMeans` approach might look like:

```
x[x<=0] <- NA
colMeans(x, na.rm=T)

#      X1       X2       X3 
#3483.664 3626.115 3533.687
```

---

Since you also mentioned you wanted to see this solution using a `for loop` you could adjust your old code to:

```
meanxpositive<-rep(NA, ncol(x))

for (n_col in 1:3) {
  z<-mean(x[which(x[,n_col]>0), n_col]) #Changed this line to reference "n_col" instead of "ncol"
  meanxpositive[n_col]<-z
}
meanxpositive
#[1] 3483.664 3626.115 3533.687
```

Note I changed references to `ncol` to `n_col` and also put in a specific selection of `n_col` in your `mean(...)` before, you weren't selecting any columns.

Lastly, with `for loops` it is best to "pre-allocate" the memory of your result. In this case that means setting it to be the size that you know it should be (3). In R growing objects inside loops is extremely slow and inefficient.

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
x<-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(-5000:7000,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your data in a data.frame,

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(47)

x <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample(-5000:7000, 1000, replace = TRUE)))

x %>% summarise_all(~mean(.x[.x > 0]))
#>         X1       X2       X3
#> 1 3578.912 3535.614 3358.444
```

or with the old `funs` notation,

```r
x %>% summarise_all(funs(mean(.[. > 0])))
#>         X1       X2       X3
#> 1 3578.912 3535.614 3358.444
```

or in base R,

```r
aggregate(. ~ TRUE, x, function(x){mean(x[x > 0])})
#>         X1       X2       X3
#> 1 3578.912 3535.614 3358.444
```

or data.table,

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, function(x){mean(x[x > 0])})]
#>          X1       X2       X3
#> 1: 3578.912 3535.614 3358.444
```